# LINQ: Group by month and year within a datetime field

Tags: linq, t-sql, group-by, substring

I have a table with a datetime field.  I want to retrieve a result set grouped by the month/year combination and the number of records that appear within that month/year.  How can this be done in LINQ?

The closest I've been able to figure out is in TSQL:

```
select substring(mo,charindex(mo,'/'),50) from (
select mo=convert(varchar(2),month(created)) + '/' + convert(varchar(4), year(created)) 
 ,qty=count(convert(varchar(2),month(created)) + '/' + convert(varchar(4), year(created)))
from posts 
group by convert(varchar(2),month(created)) + '/' + convert(varchar(4), year(created))
) a
order by substring(mo,charindex(mo,'/')+1,50)
```

But I wouldn't say that works...

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
var grouped = from p in posts
     group p by new { month = p.Create.Month,year= p.Create.Year } into d
     select new { dt = string.Format("{0}/{1}",d.Key.month,d.Key.year), count = d.Count() };
```

Here's the list of DateTime functions available in [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882657.aspx). For this to work you'll also need to understand [multi-column grouping](http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/05/07/group-by-multiple-columns-in-linq-to-sql.aspx)

ordered descending

```
var grouped = (from p in posts 
  group p by new { month = p.Create.Month,year= p.Create.Year } into d 
  select new { dt = string.Format("{0}/{1}",d.Key.month,d.Key.year), count = d.Count()}).OrderByDescending (g => g.dt);
```

Comment: i want to sort this by months like first current month at top and previous month next a nd so on?? please help

Comment: you can do that by adding an orderbydescending

Answer (score 31):

This is for those who are trying to accomplish the same but using lambda expressions.

Assuming that you already have a collection of entities and each entity has OrderDate as one of its properties.

```
yourCollection
// This will return the list with the most recent date first.
.OrderByDescending(x => x.OrderDate)
.GroupBy(x => new {x.OrderDate.Year, x.OrderDate.Month})
// Bonus: You can use this on a drop down
.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
           Value = string.Format("{0}|{1}", x.Key.Year, x.Key.Month),
           Text = string.Format("{0}/{1} (Count: {2})", x.Key.Year, x.Key.Month, x.Count())
        })
.ToList();
```

If you do not need the collection of SelectListItem then just replace the select with this one:

```
.Select(x => string.Format("{0}/{1} (Count: {2})", x.Key.Year, x.Key.Month, x.Count()))
```

Answer (score 7):

you could also do it this way

```
from o in yg
group o by o.OrderDate.ToString("MMM yyyy") into mg
select new { Month = mg.Key, Orders = mg }
```

Your result will be

{Jan 2014, 25}
{Feb 2015, 15} etc...

Comment: Works great for objects, but not for `IQueryable<>` that will get sent to a database. There you get `Method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.`

Answer (score 1):

[This Site](http://www.formatexception.com/2009/03/linq-group-by-and-groupby/) has an example that should fill your need.

This is the basic syntax:

```
from o in yg
group o by o.OrderDate.Month into mg
select new { Month = mg.Key, Orders = mg }
```

Comment: With a list containing orders from mulitple years, this will group orders from january 2010, 2011 and 2012 into the same group.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution for grouping in DateTime.

```
List<leaveallview> lav = new List<leaveallview>();
lav = dbEntity.leaveallviews.Where(m =>m.created==alldate).ToList();
dynamic lav1 = lav.GroupBy(m=>m.created.Value.GetDateTimeFormats()).FirstOrDefault().ToList();
```