# Entity Framwork, group by day/week/month working on a datetime

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

As the title says, I have a datetime column in my table.

I need to group by my records in three ways, in three different cases:

1. group by day
2. group by week
3. group by month

How can I do these 3 different group by statement in Entity Framework, with lambda expression, if possible?

**UPDATE: the linked question as duplicate, is not a real duplicate. I'm asking for the lambda solution and it isn't present in the link**

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762899/linq-group-by-month-and-year-within-a-datetime-field

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use this method :

```
var ByDayGrouped = new TestEntities().Objects.GroupBy(O => new { O.date.Year, O.date.Month, O.date.Day }).ToList();

var ByMonthGrouped = new TestEntities().Objects.GroupBy(O => new { O.date.Year, O.date.Month }).ToList();

var ByWeekGrouped = new TestEntities().Objects.GroupBy(O => (O.date.DayOfYear % 7) + M ).ToList();
```

Comment: Is the ".Objects" needed? What is it?

Comment: "Objects" is the name of my DbSet. It could be anything based on your project

Comment: What is the `M` variable in the `ByWeekGrouped` query?

Comment: it's a number, depends on which day of week you want to be as the first day of week

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
List<MyEntitiy> list = (from e in Context.MyEntities group e by e.Date.Day into g select g).ToList();
```

For  Month replace `e.Date.Day` with with `e.Date.Month`

For **Week** you must first **Calculate WeekOfYear**

```
public int GetWeekOfYear(this DateTime d)
{
    GregorianCalendar c = new  GregorianCalendar();
    return c.GetWeekOfYear(d,CalenderWeekRule.FirstDay,DayOfWeek.Sunday);
}
```

And use

```
List<MyEntitiy> list = (from e in Context.MyEntities group e by e.Date.GetWeekOfYear() into g select g).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following format using linq and lambda expressions

For Group By Day

```
    var results = from p in db.table
                          group p.data by p.DateTime.UtcNow.Day into g
                          select new { Id = g.Key, parameters = g };
```

For Group By Week

```
    var result = from p in db.table
                         group p.data by p.DateTime.UtcNow.DayOfWeek into g
                          select new { Id = g.Key, parameters = g}
```

or else

```
    //get the 7days of the week by the below method and perform between operation
    DateTime fromDate = DateTime.Today.Subtract(new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0));
    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
    var result = from p in db.table
                         group p.data by (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(today) && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(today) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(fromDate)) into g
                         select new { Id = g.Key, parameters = g}
```

similarly for Month

```
    DateTime fromDate = DateTime.Today.Subtract(new TimeSpan(30, 0, 0, 0));
    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
    var result = from p in db.table
                         group p.data by (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(today) && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(today) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(fromDate)) into g
                         select new { Id = g.Key, parameters = g}
```

Comment: Why " parameters = g.ToList()"? What is its use? It insert in "parameters" all the fields of "table"?